# Large complicated constructor or private method?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am implementing a class to represent legacy files.  The files are binary and need extensive parsing.  There will be probably thousands of lines of code to parse the file.  I have two constructors in the class:

```
class CrmxFile {

public:
    CrmxFile(std::wstring filename);
    CrmxFile(std::ifstream& file);

...
}
```

As the object doesn't make sense without the content of the file, all the parsing needs to be done while constructing the object.  I was going to implement a massive constructor (the one with the stream parameter), but a colleague of mine argues that it's not a good practice to have very large constructors.  Instead, I should create a private method that would do the parsing and call this method from the constructor after checking the stream is readable and, maybe, reading the file header to validate the stream contains correct data.

Are there any guidelines/rules/conventions/etc. that govern such situations?  Essentially (in pseudo-code), which of the two approaches is better,

long constructor:

```
CrmxFile::CrmxFile(std::ifstream& file) {
    if (file is not readable) {
        throw new CmrxException(read_error);
    }

    CmrxHeader header(file);
    if(!header.isValid()) {
        throw new CmrxException(invalid_file);
    }

    //now do all the reading/parsing of the file
    //constructor may end up being a thousand lines of code
    ...
}
```

or short constructor and helper method:

```
class CrmxFile {

public:
    CrmxFile(std::wstring filename);
    CrmxFile(std::ifstream& file);

private:
    ParseFile(std::ifstream& file);

...
}

CrmxFile::CrmxFile(std::ifstream& file) {
    if (file is not readable) {
        throw new CrmxException(read_error);
    }

    CrmxHeader header(file);
    if(!header.isValid()) {
        throw new CrmxException(invalid_file);
    }

    ParseFile(file);
}

void CrmxFile::ParseFile(std::ifstream& file) {
    //do all the reading/parsing of the file here
    ...
}
```

Comment: So your question is actually 'Large complicated constructor or large complicated private method?', and I think the answer is "Neither, don't write large complicate things in the first place". ;-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Yep, that's exactly the question :)  And as for not writing complicated things in the first place... as much as I try to break it down into smaller manageable pieces, I don't want to have extra 3000 lines of code just for method declarations and calls.

Comment: I think you're confusing lines of code with code complexity. More lines of code don't necessarily make code more complex. In fact, the opposite can be true: since you have more method declarations, you have more opporturnities to give names to pieces of code so your code will become self-documenting and your backtraces (should you need them) will be much more descriptive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The helper seems feasible here..

But, I wouldn't make it private: instead split it in several, as small as possible functions residing in a detail or parser namespace, so you can test each method. Since you use streams anyway this is a easy: change your methods to accept an `istream` instead of `ifstream` and then the input to your tests can be plain strings which you then feed into an istringstream which you use as method argument. Believe me, you will want to test this, as you say now aready it's going to be hundreds of lines there is not a chance you get it right from the first time.

The actual helper method than simply combines the smaller methods, or depending on how much of them you have, combines smaller methods which in turn combine others.

Comment: Good approach, I just want to say that it is **never** a good idea to have one monstrous function, no matter if it is a constructor or a helper-function. You should always try to break it down in several helper functions. My personal target for the maximal length of a function is always around 10 lines, give or take.

Comment: I certainly appreciate the fact that the code needs to be split up into smaller manageable pieces.  Yet, the main driver will still be quite large...

Comment: @AleksG: will it ? Or will you package the manageable pieces into several manageable pieces that will themselves be packaged in manageable pieces.... and finally, at some point, the "driver" will only contain a couple lines of code ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. And then overall I'll have 5,000 lines of code instead of 3,000 due to all the new method definitions, macros and calls... I'm all for code maintainability, but I'm also being pragmatic here.  The parsing only needs to happen once.

Comment: @AleksG: I am pragmatic too: how do you test a 3000 lines method ? Where do you start to investigate if anything goes wrong ? Small chunks of code (though 10 lines might be cutting it short) are just *more* manageable (and testable). I personally draw the lines at functions that cannot fit within my screen, but very often I have smaller ones.

Comment: @MatthieuM I probably didn't express myself well.  I'm not writing a 3000 lines method.  It's going to be a method of about 500-600 lines, which calls other things, which in turn call yet other things - totalling closer to 3000 lines.  (This is an estimate only at this stage.)  If I were to split that even further, then I'm getting to pretty much wrap every 10 lines or so into a separate method and I'll get bogged down with the complexity of nested calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple constructors then it is a good idea to have a private method to do the initialization. Saves repeating code (thus aid in being more maintainable and less prone to errors in the event of any changes being made).

If just one constructor just make it as complicated as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this really matters unless you want to share the private helper method for other uses or multiple constructors inside the object.

The approach of parsing inside the constructor sounds problematic to me. This is a mix of construction and initialization roles. You may want to expose the parsing as a public interface and the constructor will only set the state of the object to non-initialized to mark the object as unusable to clients. Alternatively, you might want to try to apply the singleton pattern here with lazy evaluation: implement the `getInstance` method which will invoke private `parse` if not already parsed - from user perspective it will be transparent (excluding the overhead of first access).

Answer (score 0):

I would say "do not do it in the constructor, period".

Constructors are strange beasts, and failure during construction is only possibly by throwing an exception.  And corrupt/invalid files, or parsing errors, are too common (in my opinion) to throw -- plus, making throwing during construction and parsing safe is challenging, and people often get it wrong.

So follow an easier path.

Write a factory function, or even a factory object, that produces your object.  It maintains parsing state, and has a myriad of functions (or, if you must, one big one) that parse the object.  Then, once the parse is finished, the object is returned, and that object doesn't have a pile of code (or state) that is associated with parsing it from disk.

This means instead of

```
try {
  MyObject foo("file.blah");
  // ...
} catch (MyObject::ParseError err) {
  // ...
}
```

you instead do something like:

```
MyObjectParser parser;
parser.Load("file.blah");
if (parser.Error()) {
  // ...
} else {
  MyObject foo = parser.Get();
  // ...
}
```

and you have the situation that the only `MyObject` that exists should be a good `MyObject` that is already loaded.